# getting a byte array from a pinned object

Tags: c#, unmanaged, managed

It is possible to get a pointer from a managed array

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[length + byteAlignment];
GCHandle bufferHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr  ptr = bufferHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

is there any way to do the opposite. getting a byte array from a pinned object without copying?

Comment: That requires unsafe code so you can use byte* (pointer to byte).  There's very little you can do with such a pointer that won't blow your leg off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's what `Marshal.Copy` is for - there is no way (well, no way without copying of some variety) to otherwise get memory between the managed and unmanaged states...well, that's not 100% true, but I'm assuming you don't want to rely solely on Win32/C and p/invoke to copy memory around.

`Marshal.Copy` use would look like:

```
IntPtr addressOfThing = ....;
byte[] buffer = new byte[...];
Marshal.Copy(addressOfThing, buffer, 0, bufferSize);
```