# Get Type of object and then cast it?

Tags: c#, unsafe

I'm trying to do a little "memcpy" hack in C#. I keep getting stuck on this part, because it won't convert System.Type to byte*

```
    public unsafe void memcpy(byte* dest, object src, int length)
    {
        byte* nsrc;
        byte* ndst;
        nsrc = (byte*)((src.GetType())src);

    }
```

As you see I try to get the type of the object, and then cast it to the original object.

Any ideas?

Update:

Maybe using serialization?

```
    private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    private void memcpy(byte[] dest, int pos, object src, int len)
    {
        byte[] ba = ObjectToByteArray(src);
        Array.Copy(ObjectToByteArray(src), 0, dest, pos, len);
    }
```

Comment: What good would that do to you? A cast is only useful when you know the type at compile time... Anyway, what are you trying to accomplish? What do you expect the type of src to be ?

Comment: C# is not C/C++ you can't just cast things willy nilly. It is a typesafe language, a reference cannot be cast to a pointer.

Comment: I assume this is what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141172/getting-a-byte-array-from-a-pinned-object

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I expect the type to be multiple values at compile time.

Comment: @user1594121, that won't work... anything that is convertible to a pointer has to be a pointer, and a pointer is not an object, so such a cast could never work.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I updated, maybe that'll work?

Comment: @user1594121 what is your goal here? Are you trying to assemble a buffer? Because there are **MUCH** better ways.

Comment: You seem to confuse compile-time types and runtime types and instances of `System.Type`. An expression like `(src.GetType())src` is not legal, and the intention behind it does not make sense, really.

Comment: @Mgetz yes and no, I want to use address's, it looks nicer, it's faster, and cleaner. also maybe I should serialize, then use pointers to copy the data?

Comment: @user1594121 just use a `MemoryStream` and then use [`BitConverter.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) messing around with pointers in C# is a great way to shoot yourself in the foot, particularly when the functionality to do what you're intending is already built into the framework and does not require `unsafe`.

Comment: what do you effectively want to do with the object variable?...get its value?..other thing?

Answer (score 3):

Not clear what you want, but maybe this is helpful?

```
int yourInt32 = ...;
byte[] bitsFromInt32Value = BitConverter.GetBytes(yourInt32);

long yourInt64 = ...;
byte[] bitsFromInt64Value = BitConverter.GetBytes(yourInt64);
```

Answer (score 0):

taken from msdn:

> Pointer types do not inherit from object and no conversions exist
>   between pointer types and object. Also, boxing and unboxing do not
>   support pointers. However, you can convert between different pointer
>   types and between pointer types and integral types.

link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=vs.100).aspx

```
            int number = 200;

            unsafe
            {
                // Convert to byte:
                byte* p = (byte*)&number;
            }
```